# Simple analytic examples of Multi-scale Entanglement Renormalization Ansatz (MERA)

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement, renormalization, spin-chains, tensor-network

I want to understand Multi-scale Entanglement Renormalization Ansatz (MERA) with very elementary examples. So far I could find references which are mostly based on numerics. It would be a great help if someone could give a very simple example explaining the basic concepts of MERA or give some references (papers/theses/reviews) that implement the operations (i.e, isometry and disentangler) in analytic fashion (even for a simplest possible system).

Actually, I do not have any 'practical' knowledge about tensor networks in general as I am from theoretical HEP background. So references on (analytic) MPS or PEPS with simple examples will be really useful.

Comment: @Qmechanic What is the motivation to convert this to a resource question? After all, the OP asks whether *someone could give a very simple example explaining the basic concepts of MERA* **or** give some references.  As far as I can see, making it a resource question invalidates the first part of the question?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: It is a borderline judgement. The CW could perhaps be converted e.g. if the thread receive another type of answers.

Answer (score 5):

The canonical example for MPS (in fact, the first MPS ever) is the [AKLT model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKLT_model) (http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.59.799, https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104161001). The 2nd reference also discusses the 2D (=PEPS) version of the state.

Another example of an exact MPS/PEPS model are (nearest-neighbor) RVB states (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0601075, http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4816); in one dimension, this is known as the [Majumdar-Ghosh model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majumdar%E2%80%93Ghosh_model).

Also, all string-net models (non-chiral topological fixed point models) can be exactly expressed as PEPS: http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.2393, https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.2821.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to start from the paper  [Entanglement Renormalization: an introduction](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.1651). In this work author describes basic consepts of MERA, things like isometries and disentanglers and why one needs to use them in order to produce MERA. 
 Article [Algorithms for entanglement renormalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0707.1454v4.pdf) is more advanced and is focused mainly on description of algorithm itself. It will be a good exercise to build MERA for simple Hamiltonian based on information provided in aforementioned article.